# C run time error #3

Tags: c, runtime-error

I keep getting the run time error 3 - The variable 'gl' is being used without being initialized. The code complies and runs fine until it uses 'gl' near the end of the code.

gl is meant to be a single character.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<varargs.h>
#include<time.h>
#define false 0
#define true 1        

/*This function works out if the number giver is a whole number, and it's greater than 3 chraters long*/
int numeric( char *string)
{
    unsigned int i;
    int valid = true;

    for (i=0;i<strlen(string); i++)
    {
        {
            if (string[i] < '0' || string[i] > '9' )    /*Check to make sure that only numeric chraters have been entered*/
                valid=false;
        }
    }

    return valid;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char gl,c;                             /*gl number of guesses, Most recently read character*/
    int t, n, gc, i, e, lc = 0, wordcount; /* Lc is the number of astericks left,Number of woods in a file*/
    short in_word;                         /*Ture or False variable*/
    char guessword[50];                    /*This is the word that get's copied from the file*/
    char selectword[50];                   /*Is copied from guessword, need change it's size to that of lc, and to then print *'s in place of charaters*/
    int chars_in_word = 0;
    FILE *file;

    wordcount=0;

    if (argc==3)
    {
        printf("The arguments supplied is %s\n",argv[1]);
    }
    else if (argc>3)
    {
        printf("too many aguments.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (argc<3)
    {
        printf("too few arguments.\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (! numeric(argv[2])) /*Checking that string with the numeric function*/
    {
        printf("Invalid input, seconed arugment is not an int");
        return 3;  /*Exiting programing if the funcation numeric turns false*/
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Arguments ok.\n");
        gc=atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );      /* Check file wordtext.text can be opened */

    if (file==0)
    {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        perror("");
        return 4;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File opening ok.\n");
    }

    in_word=false;

    while ((c=fgetc(file))!=EOF) /* word count*/
    {
        if(c!=' ' &&  c!= '.' && c!= ',' && c!='\t'&& c!= '\n')
        {
            if (! in_word)
            {
                wordcount++;
                in_word=true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            in_word=false;
        }
    }

    if ((fclose(file))==EOF)
    {
        printf("%s: Error closing file '%s'\n", argv[2]);
        perror("");
        return 5;
    }

    printf("%d\n",wordcount);

    srand(time(NULL));       /*Random number Generator*/
    for (t=1;t<=150;t++)
    {
        n=(rand() % wordcount + 1);
    }
    printf("%d\n", n);
    i=0;

    file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );   /* I've not worked out how to skip to the selected word (wordcount)*/

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '.')
        {
            guessword[chars_in_word] = c;
            chars_in_word++;
        }
        else
        {
            guessword[chars_in_word] = '\0';
            chars_in_word=0;
            i++;
            if ( i == n )
            {
                fclose(file);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Word guess: %s\n",guessword);  /*change this into an array*/

    e=0;

    for (e = 0; e<guessword[e]; e++) {
        if (guessword!="\0")
        {                           
            printf("*");
            lc++;
        }
    }

    printf("\n%d\n",lc);
    printf("Number of guesses left %d\n",gc);
    printf("Enter guess:   ");
    scanf("%s", gl);
    printf("%s",gl);

    /*While number of guesses != 0*/
    /*count = length of guessword*/
    /*Enter guess*/
    /*If guess = char*/
    /*print that char, count (lc) - 1*/
    /*If count = 0*/ 
    /*Well done*/
    /*if number of guesses = 0*/
    /*Hard luck*/
    return 0;  
}
```

I've looked online but only found stuff to do with ints and reals. anyone have any ideas. sorry if this seems very basic stuff.

Comment: Consider inluding `<stdbool.h>` instead of defining `true` and `false` yourself. Also, you might want to replace `<varargs.h>` with `<stdarg.h>`.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

`gl` is declared as `char` in your program but `s` conversion specifier requires a `char *`.  Be sure to pass a pointer to the first element of a `char` array object.

```
scanf("%s", gl);
printf("%s",gl);
```

Before continuing, turn on all warnings in your compiler and fix them all.

Answer (score 1):

`gl` is a `char`, not a string.  Passing a non-pointer to `scanf()` is never going to set a value for that variable.  It will also fail as an `%s` parameter to `printf()`.

Redeclare `gl` as:

```
char gl[50];
```